# What is the escape character for SSIS Expression Builder?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, expressionbuilder

I need to escape quotation marks in SQL Server Integration Services' Expression Builder.  I cannot escape it with double or triple quotes.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Backslash "\" is the escape character.

Example: "SELECT branch, \"tran-date\" FROM TellerTransaction"