# How to correctly parse SSIS variable expression?

Tags: ssis

I created an SSIS variable, which I want to turn into an expression, so I write this as the Expression:

="\\livprodad1.liv.local\UserProfiles$\mike.jones\Documents\Files"

The actual link that I am referencing is:
\livprodad1.liv.local\UserProfiles$\mike.jones\Documents\Files

But I get this message: Expression can not be evaluated
Attempt to parse the expression failed. The expression might contain an invalid token, an incomplete token, or an invalid element. It might not be well-formed, or might be missing part of a required element such as a parenthesis.

What am I doing wrong? How should it be written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to double all the slashes in an expression so

```
"\livprodad1.liv.local\UserProfiles$\mike.jones\Documents\Files"
```

becomes

```
"\\livprodad1.liv.local\\UserProfiles$\\mike.jones\\Documents\\Files"
```

And if you were intending to encode

```
"\\livprodad1.liv.local\UserProfiles$\mike.jones\Documents\Files"
```

it would become

```
"\\\\livprodad1.liv.local\\UserProfiles$\\mike.jones\\Documents\\Files"
```

The leading equals sign might point to a different issue as the only explicit location that I can think of where one assigns a value is in the Expression Task. Everywhere else, there's a separate field where you list the variable you are modifying

And if the double quote is part of the expression itself, then you also escape it with a backslash `\"` Excellent example of escaping both on [What is the escape character for SSIS Expression Builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255273/what-is-the-escape-character-for-ssis-expression-builder)

Comment: you missed the first \ in the UNC path, should be

"\\livprodad1.liv.local\UserProfiles$\mike.jones\Documents\Files"
becomes

"\\\\livprodad1.liv.local\\UserProfiles$\\mike.jones\\Documents\\Files"

Comment: @MLeblanc I went with the "The actual link that I am referencing is:" value they provided